# Am I able to wait until one object is destroyed until it creates another and time.sleep() in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.85, )

def destroymole():
    mole.destroy()

xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)
ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)

mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=destroymole, height=1, width=10, bg="brown")
mole.config(command=mole.destroy)
mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

for i in range(15):

    xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 50)
    ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 50)

    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", height=1, width=10, bg="brown")
    mole.config(command=mole.destroy)
    mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

   root.mainloop()
```

I can delete specific buttons however I only want to create 1 mole at a time.
Also, it would be nice for 1 second of delay before creating another one.

`time.sleep(2)` does 30 seconds of rest because it is looped 15 times.

Comment: You could make a command, which creates a mole, and then use root.after() to call the command again after a specified delay. You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/

Comment: instead `sleep` you could use `after(millisecond, function_name)` to execute function which run other code. And if you want only one item then at start set `mole = None` and when you try to create new button then check if it is still `None`. And when you destroy it then set again `mole = None`

Comment: you could reduce code to keep only buttons without frame, colors, other decorations.

Comment: use `Button( commad=...)` or `mole.config(command=...)` - not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to destroy and recreate the <kbd>MOLE</kbd>.  You can just hide and show the same button in random position.

You can hide the button when it is clicked and use `.after()` to show it back after 1 second:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=600, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relwidth=0.85, relheight=0.85)

def randvalue():
    return random.randrange(100, 500, 30)

def destroymole():
    # hide the MOLE button
    mole.place_forget()
    # show the MOLE button in random position after one second
    mole.after(1000, lambda: mole.place(x=randvalue(), y=randvalue()))

mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", width=10, bg="brown", command=destroymole)
mole.place(x=randvalue(), y=randvalue())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one button then don't use `for`-loop for this.

You should have function `create_mole` to create button. And button should run function which destroys existing button and it use `after()` to run `create_mole` again after 1s (1000ms)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def create_mole():
    global mole  # need it to assing button to external/global variable `mole` 
                 # and later to access `mole` in `destroy_mole`
    
    xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)
    ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)

    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", command=destroy_mole)
    mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

def destroy_mole():
    mole.destroy()
    # run it after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, create_mole)
    
# --- main ----

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

create_mole()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to display button only 15 times then you use variable to count displayed button and use it to execute `after()`

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def create_mole():
    global mole  # need it to assing button to external/global variable `mole` 
                 # and later to access `mole` in `destroy_mole`
    
    
    xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)
    ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 30)

    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", command=destroy_mole)
    mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

def destroy_mole():
    global counter # need it to assing counter to external/global variable `counter`         
    
    mole.destroy()
    
    counter -= 1
    
    if counter > 0:
        # run it after 1000ms (1s)
        root.after(1000, create_mole)
    else:
        # close program or do something different
        root.destroy()
        
# --- main ----

counter = 15

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

create_mole()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tysm, I can actually understand this, and it works!